# Xcode Static librari error ignoring file , file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static-libraries

i get this error when i am trying to use my compiled  static library in my iphone aplication. I have no frigging idea what's wrong.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/rw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MSTicketingSaaS-gkznscznevvifjesoapzgwycbces/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMylib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppData", referenced from:
```

It worked before upgrading to Xcode 4.0.2

I added the i386 architecture and now it compiles for the simulator but NOT for the device.

Comment: you getting this in the simulator only?

Comment: i'm testing on the device and simulator , same errors ob bowth

Comment: have you tried to rebuild your static library?

Comment: Yes I tried making a clean build , and i tried building it with every combination of Build settings i could think of, only thing that works is downgrading the x code

Answer (score 2):

Check with `lipo` which is the architecture your lib has been built for:

```
lipo -info <path_to_lib>
```

If it does not contain "arm6" then you should go back to the library project and build it for the proper architecture. If this does not help, please, give more detail about the structure of your project(s).

Comment: i had same issue, and using lobo it shows Non-fat file: libopus.a is architecture: armv7